# Mocha/Chai testing expected vs actual arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, matcher, chai

What's the best way to assert that the expected results matches the actual results when both are arrays of objects?  My immediate thought was to use Array prototype filter and check that the intersection is the same size as expected, i.e.:

```
describe('select',function(){
  it("should return selected columns", function(done) {
    var query = "select lunchTime, name";

    var actual = ... results of the query, an array of anonymous objects ...

    // expected results
    var expected = [{"lunchTime": "12:00:00", "name": "John"}, 
                   {"lunchTime": "12:00:00", "name": "Dave"}, 
                   {"lunchTime": "13:00:00", "name": "Sally"}, 
                   {"lunchTime": "12:00:00", "name": "Ben"}, 
                   {"lunchTime": "12:00:00", "name": "Dana"}, 
                   {"lunchTime": "13:00:00", "name": "Mike"}];

    var intersection = actual.filter(function(n) {
        return expected.indexOf(n) != -1
    });

    expect(intersection).to.have.length(expected.length);
    expect(actual).to.have.length(expected.length);
  });
});
```

Does this approach make sense?  Is there a better way to assert the query results match expectations?

Comment: btw - I'm testing the query language implementation, so the query is the sut

Answer (score 14):

As you noted, for sets, you can use:

```
expect(actual).to.have.members(expected);
```

This will fail if there are any members in `expected` that are not in `actual`, and vice versa.

You can also do:

```
expect(actual).to.contain.members(expected);
```

Which will fail if there are members in `expected` that are not in `actual`, but will *not* fail if there are members in `actual` that are not in `expected`.  (In other words, `actual` must be a superset of `expected`).

If you're comparing objects, you probably want to deep compare:

```
expect(actual).to.deep.have.same.members(expected);
```

e.g.:

```
expect([{a:'a'}, {a:'b'}]).to.deep.have.same.members([{a:'a'}, {a:'b'}]);
```

(edited: `to.have.same.members()` is actually the same as `to.have.members()`.)

Answer (score 7):

Chai has a [members matcher](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members) that does what I need:

```
expect(actual).to.have.members(expected);
```